# How do I make a new columns, for each same value in column1 and as their data, their sum in column2?

Tags: sql, plsql

I've a database like this:

```
    |productno | type | quantity |    
    |180001   | hms1 | 15000  |    
    |180001   | hms1 | 12400  |    
    |180001   | hms1 | 13600  |    
    |180001   | hms2 | 24599  | 
    |180002   | pik  | 88888  |    
    |180002   | hms1 | 55000  |    
    |180002   | hms1 | 22500  |
```

and list contuniues...
What I want to accomplish is to select sum of hms1(or every other value) for every product no, like this.

```
select productno, hms1, hms2, pik    
from database
```

and result should look like this

```
|productno| hms1| hms2| pik |    
|----------------------------     
|180001  | 41000 | 24599 |  0   |      
|180002  | 77500 |   0  | 88888 |
```

There are total 5 type of value in type column. So no need to do something automated. I tried to use sum like this :

```
select productNo, sum (case when type='hms1' then quantity end) as hms1   
from database group by productNo
```

but hms1 returns null, or zero if I add "else 0" to sum function.

How do I accomplish this in PL/SQL? Sorry for unclear header, I lost in translation.

Comment: Try `select *, type='hms1' as is_hms1 from database` first. It should put a TRUE next to any column with hms1 as type. If not, your type column might for instance have leading blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query for what you want should look like this:

```
select productNo,
       sum(case when type = 'hms1' then quantity end) as hms1, 
       sum(case when type = 'hms2' then quantity end) as hms2, 
       sum(case when type = 'pik' then quantity end) as pik 
from database
group by productNo;
```

If there are no matches, then the string constants are not what you expect.  One common problem are spaces at the beginning or end, so you can try:

```
select productNo,
       sum(case when trim(type) = 'hms1' then quantity end) as hms1, 
       sum(case when trim(type) = 'hms2' then quantity end) as hms2, 
       sum(case when trim(type) = 'pik' then quantity end) as pik 
from database
group by productNo;
```

If this doesn't work, then the problem is more subtle -- some other type of hidden characters.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping . . . I don't find the `pivot` syntax to be useful.  I can do everything that it does -- and much more -- using conditional aggregation.  I find the result queries to be simpler to understand as well.